# Violating rule of reflexivity when overriding equals method

Tags: java, collections

I have a doubt from the book Efective Java. The doubt is regarding equals method
reflexive rule violation. The book says the following:

> "*If you were to violate it and then add an instance of your class to a collection, the collection's contains method would almost certainly say that the collection did not contain the instance that you just added.*"

To test it I wrote an example class, but the contains method doesn't return `false` It returns `true`. Can anybody tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflexive means `x.equals(x)` should return `true`

```
class Foo {
   int i;
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return ((Foo) obj).i < this.i;
   }
}
```

this will return `false`. And when you put it into a list and call `list.contains(foo)` it will return false, because none of the elements in the list was equal to the one you passed. This is so because `list.contains(..)` iterates the elements and for each of them checks `if (elem.equals(arg))`

See the docs of [`Collection.contains(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: *And when you put it into a list and call list.contains(foo) it will return false*... Not true for collections in general though: http://ideone.com/Apd1T

Comment: @aioobe - that's interesting. It actually breaks the contract defined by the `Collection` and `Set` interfaces. (I linked the docs)

Comment: @Bozho: no, it doesn't break the contract, because the contract only applies to objects that don't break the `equals()`/`hashCode()` contract either. And the class in the sample *clearly* breaks the `equals()` contract. It's a classical crap-in-crap-out situation.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer it says it relies solely on what `equals(..)` returns, and in fact it doesn't.

Comment: @Bozho: and it does **if** `equals()` is implemented in a way that is specification-conforming. In general, **nothing** can be guaranteed when the objects you use don't conform to the specification. The same is true for `hashCode()`: if you implement it wrongly, then a `HashSet` will break spectacularly. Note that the code it gives is *specification* (that has to be read in the context of the other specifications surrounding it) and not necessarily the code that's used to implement it!

Comment: Of course I agree you should not expect logical results if you break the equals contract. But the implementation should use equals if it is defined to do so. It will return `true` if equals is implemented correctly. With the hashCode example - what if the implementation used identityHashCode somewhere, even though it is not specified to do so?

Comment: @Bozho: if it doesn't document it, then it's clearly breaking the contract. Note, however that all cases that I know of *do* document it. [`IdentityHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) for example clearly states that "... it intentionally violates `Map`'s general contract, ...".

Comment: well, identityHashCode is to hashCode is as == is to equals. The thing is, `HashSet` only violates it in one specific scenario (which is not supposed to occur anyway)

Answer (score 6):

I agree that the result of this program is [indeed puzzling](http://ideone.com/VBZ7dN):

```
import java.util.*;

class Item {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return false;   // not even equal to itself.
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
        Item i = new Item();
        items.add(i);
        System.out.println(items.contains(i));   // Prints true!
    }
}
```

The answer is that the `contains` implementation checks `argument == object` before doing `argument.equals(object)`. The result from `contains` is `true` since `item == item` holds, even though `item.equals(item)` returns false.

**Assuming `equals` follows its contract** (is reflexive), this way of implementing `contains` is correct.

---

If you read the quote you posted carefully, **the author includes the word "*almost*"** :) It seems you stumbled across one of the few exceptions to the rule.

---

Other collections (`ArrayList` for instance) uses `equals` directly, and if you change from `new HashSet<Item>()` to `new ArrayList<Item>()` in the above program it [prints `false`](http://ideone.com/SeyEY) as expected.